# Glyphicons Pro in Bootsrap 3 / Icon not aligned with Text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I just included the Glyphicons pro font into my Bootstrap project. The icons are displayed but the icon alignment e.g. in a button is not correct.

What do I have to change to use the Glyphicons Pro Set like Halflings?

[image: Button 1 = glyphicons pro | Button 2 = glyphicon halflings]

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
   <span class="glyphicons glyphicons-lightbulb"></span> Button 1
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span> Button 2
</button>
```

Comment: can you please paste you code

Comment: example - `<a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print 
    </a>`

Comment: upload your css part

Comment: you are using glyph icons and glyphicon https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/bb61c412/462/

Comment: css Part is default bootstrap.
I am using glyphicons (pro version) and glyphcion (default bootstrap - halflings) works fine.. but not the alignment in a <button>

Answer (score 0):

Move the text out of the `<span>` with the glyphicon and apply `vertical-align:middle` to the

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-lightbulb"  style="vertical-align:middle"></span> Button 1
</button>
```

Comment: My text is not inside the span ;)

Comment: its not going  align the  text

Answer (score 0):

Override the standard vertical alignment ("top") of glyphicons pro by adding "!important" to the css statement:

```
.glyphicons {
    vertical-align:middle !important;
}
```